# Deformation of stable curve with regular total space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, let $X/k$ be a stable curve. Is it always possible to find a deformation $\mathcal{X}/k[[t]]$ such that $\mathcal{X}$ is regular?

(Sorry for the confusion, this is a duplication of one of my previous post....The answer to this question is yes, by Theorem B.2 in Brian Conrad’s Appendix to “Specialization of linear systems from curves to graphs”
by Matthew Baker.)

Comment: It looks like you ask a question and answer it at the same time … what is the question, then?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry for the confusion, I asked the question and realized it was a duplicate, but I couldn’t close the question.

Comment: In that situation, you can flag your post for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for $k$ algebraically closed. 
First of all, for each singularity, we can choose a local deformation over $k[[t]]$ such that the total space around this singularity is regular. In some local coordinates it can be written as $k[[x, y, t]] / (xy-t)$. To get a global deformation, one uses the local-global principle (1.5) of Deligne--Mumford.